# calculate distance from NA pixel to the nearest nonNA pixel in raster

Tags: r, terra

I have the below spatraster:

```
class       : SpatRaster 
dimensions  : 6000, 6000, 1  (nrow, ncol, nlyr)
resolution  : 0.0008333333, 0.0008333333  (x, y)
extent      : 54.99958, 59.99958, -25.00042, -20.00042  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
source      : prj2050_2090.tif 
name        : high_2090 
min value   :      0.0100 
max value   :      0.2055
```

The raster contains flood depth. There are many locations where the flood depth is NA. I want to calculate for every pixel, distance
to the nearest flooded pixel. If a pixel has non-NA values, the distance should be 0. If a pixel has NA values, the distance to the
nearest flooded pixel should be assigned.

```
library(terra)
dist <- terra::distance(my_raster)
```

When I run the above code, my R studio crashes. Is it because this is too heavy a computation for my laptop or I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Look at terra::gridDistance instead. For origins parameter provide NULL as you want to propagate distance from flooded pixels to NA pixels. Bear in mind that distance is propagated from cell to cell and will not be exactly the same as euclidian distance from nearest flooded pixel of a NA pixel